# Regex to remove whitespace in between quotes but not between words inside the quotes?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am programming in Java.

I am struggling to transform this:

```
Text0 Text1 " Text2 Text3 Text4     "   Text5 Text6
```

into this:

```
Text0 Text1 "Text2 Text3 Text4" Text5 Text6
```

I have tried lookaheads and lookbehinds:

> (?<=\")\s+(\w*\s*\w*)\s+(?=\")

manages to match all the text inside the quotes, but when switching to:

> (?<=\")\s+(\W*\S*\W*)\s+(?=\")

I get an error. Not sure why.

My short knowledge of regex limits me. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better to show what you've tried and what results these attempts brought you.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter thank you, just added the information.

Comment: Not a java pro, would something like `replaceAll("\" *([^\"]+)? *\"", "\"$1\"") ` work? Is that valid regex syntax in java?

Comment: This needs context (am I inside or outside quotes), which generally disqualifies regex as a proper way to implement a solution.

Comment: @PaulHodges you might want to use `+?` instead of `+` in the middle of that, since a space isn't a quote, and so would otherwise be matched greedily.

Comment: @Aaron the quoted text in the question is all within a string, there are no quotes but the ones showed, there could possibly more than 1 set of quotes.

Comment: [Match `"\s*([^"\s]+(?:\s[^"\s]+)*)\s*"` / Replace by `"\1"`](https://regex101.com/r/13bZBY/1) ? I expect some pitfalls.

Comment: @Aaron wow, that worked beautifully. What are some of the pitfalls that could occur? I tried breaking it, but haven't been successful yet.

Comment: @Yokhen After some thoughts as long as you don't have any unbalanced quotes it should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier not to use (just) regex.

Split the string on quotes (-1 to keep any trailing empty parts):

```
String[] parts = str.split("\"", -1);
```

Trim the odd-numbered elements:

```
for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
  parts[i] = parts[i].trim();
}
```

Join the parts again:

```
String newStr = String.join("\"", parts);
```

Comment: That does help. Do you know if it's also time/resource efficient as compared to regex? Just general curiosity, not really a requirement.

Comment: It will have... different efficiency. Hard to say. Regexes are generally pretty inefficient. You can do it more efficiently using a StringBuilder, avoiding creating the intermediate strings this does.